# Как добавить в массив новый уровень?

Tags: php

Имею такой PHP код:

```
$goodname = 'name';
$goodlvl = '6';

    $name = "goods.json";
    $arr = array(
        'name' => $goodname,
        'lvl' => $goodlvl
    );
    file_put_contents($name, json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Он создает массив PHP, преобразует в формат JSON и пихает в `goods.json`

Вроде всё работает, но не так как мне надо. Вот что этот скрипт делает с файлом `goods.json`:

```
{"name":"123","lvl":"6"}
```

Он переносит элементы массива. Хочу узнать, как заставить PHP скрипт давать этому массиву название, чтобы получилось что-то вроде этого

```
{
   "account" : {
      "name: "123", "lvl" : "6" 
   }
}
```

Всё для того чтобы потом можно было создавать эти аккаунты и указывать (вбивать в input'ы) статистику: имя и уровень, а PHP скрипт их создавал и заносил в `goods.json`

Comment: Есть ещё аналог кода, результат естественно, тот же. Что надо сделать, блин, чтобы он идентифицировал как-то эти массивы?
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/140e8f7d8a355593c85778cd3e1f89f67fc947de

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дайте массиву имя, и оно поместится в json
    $goodname = 'name';
    $goodlvl = '6';

```
$name = "goods.json";
$arr = array(
    "player" => array (
        'name' => $goodname,
        'lvl' => $goodlvl
        )
);
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Выведет: `{"player":{"name":"name","lvl":"6"}}`

Comment: Плюс `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

Comment: спасибо всем огромное)

Answer (score 3):

Чтоб получить из вашего кода такой json текс:

`{
   "account" : {
      "name: "123", "lvl" : "6" 
   }
}`

Ваш код должен иметь следующий вид:

```
$goodname = '123';
$goodlvl = '6';
$name = "goods.json";
$arr = array(
    'name' => $goodname,
    'lvl' => $goodlvl
);
//тут ваш массив кладем в массив другой массив
$account_array = array(
    'account' => $arr 
);
//заметьте тут поменялся массив источник вместо $arr мы кодируем в json $account_array
file_put_contents($name, json_encode($account_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Comment: спасибо) странно что я до этого не додумался, хотя что-то подобное пытался сотворить